# Como faço para select multiple permitir que selecione somente um item?

Tags: html, jquery

Possuo um select:

```
<select multiple="multiple"> 
<option value="0">teste</option>
<option value="1">teste 1</option>
<option value="2">teste 2</option>
<option value="3">teste 3</option>
<option value="4">teste 4</option>
<option value="5">teste 5</option>
</select>
```

Nesse select gostaria de poder selecionar somente 1 item da lista, porém quero que apareça todos os itens em formato lista, por isso o uso do multiple, como poderia resolver isso?

Obs: eu nao vou poder usar a propriedade `size` pois o tamanho da lista é dinâmica, a lista vem do back-end.

Answer (score 2):

Meu colega, você está usando o atributo `multiple` para poder selecionar várias opções na lista suspensa, esse é o real objetivo do atributo `multiple`(selecionar vários elementos). Para você poder fazer com que os elementos `<option>` sejam todos exibidos você pode usar o atributo `size` com o valor definido para `6` que é a quantidade de elementos `<option>` no elemento `<select>`, isso é para poder amostrar um número determinado de elementos visíveis na lista suspensa:

**Exemplo**

```html
<select size="6"> 
     <option value="0">teste</option>
     <option value="1">teste 1</option>
     <option value="2">teste 2</option>
     <option value="3">teste 3</option>
     <option value="4">teste 4</option>
     <option value="5">teste 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: eu dei um exemplo ao colocar 6 itens no select, eu nao vou poder usar o size pois o tamanho da lista é dinamica, a lista vem do back end.

Comment: @Stand Alone, se isso também era o que você deseja, então tinha que ter colocado isso na pergunta também.

Comment: Ok irei editar adicionando isso obrigado.